# github内にherokuのDeployボタンを設置する

Tags: heroku, github

githubのプロジェクトのトップにREADME.mdファイルとapp.jsonファイルを置いています。

おそらく中の記述に不備があり、ボタンは表示されるのですが、押すとherokuに新規アプリの作成を促されます。
新規アプリを作るとデプロイできのですが、一度viewで表示しているタブを閉じ、再びgithub内のDeployボタンを押すとまた新規アプリの作成を促されていしまいます。

記述に足りていない点があれば教えてください。

app.json

```
{   
　"name": "node-static-site"
}
```

README.md

```
[![Deploy](https://www.herokucdn.com/deploy/button.png)](https://heroku.com/deploy)
```

また、現状使っているサービスはgithub・heroku共に無料で、herokuのアドオンなどは一切使っていません。
ご指摘、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The ‘Deploy to Heroku’ button enables users to deploy apps to Heroku without leaving the web browser, and with little or no configuration. The button is ideal for customers, open-source project maintainers or add-on providers who wish to provide their customers with a quick and easy way to deploy and configure a Heroku app. 
>   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-button

とあるように、オープンソースのアプリケーションなどで、最初のデプロイ（インストールや追加とでも言いましょうか）を簡単にするボタンが Deploy to Heroku ボタンです。

ですからタブを開きなおしてもう一度ボタンを押せば、新規アプリとしてデプロイできる、というのは正しい挙動だと思います。既にデプロイ済みのアプリケーションを更新したい場合は、 `git push` 等を行わなければいけません。